# Unable to install node via nvm in Cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

When I try to use the "nvm install" command, it seems to run fine but at the very end I get the following long error message:

```
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
Warning: Missing input files:
/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/tools\msvs\genfiles\node_etw_provider.rc
/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/tools\msvs\genfiles\node_etw_provider.h
/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/deps/v8/gypfiles/..\src\parsing\preparse-data-format.h
/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/tools\msvs\genfiles\node_perfctr_provider.rc
/usr/bin/python2.7 tools/gyp_node.py -f make
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
  touch 7943452e36215487f7a1b8edf63ca06ddfd83538.intermediate
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/out/Release/lib.host:/home/Dinghy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.20.1/files/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../.; mkdir -p tools/msvs/genfiles; "mc src/res/node_etw_provider.man -h tools/msvs/genfiles -r tools/msvs/genfiles"
/bin/sh: mc src/res/node_etw_provider.man -h tools/msvs/genfiles -r tools/msvs/genfiles: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [node_etw.target.mk:17: 7943452e36215487f7a1b8edf63ca06ddfd83538.intermediate] Error 127
rm 7943452e36215487f7a1b8edf63ca06ddfd83538.intermediate
make: *** [Makefile:99: node] Error 2
nvm: install v10.20.1 failed!
```

I've also tried installing it manually but haven't had any success that way either. This worked fine on an old install of cygwin I had, so I'm not sure what the problem is on this new install.